# можно ли вставить html код в youtube комментарии

Tags: html, youtube, комментарии

Например мне нужно вставить картинку в [youtube](http://youtube.com) комментарий возможно ли это реализовать даже самым костыльным образом. Если нет то так и напишите.

Comment: Нет. Максимум что можно ascii графика =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Даже самым костыльным способом не получится. 
Вот, как ты можешь редактировать текст в комментариях:

1. Чтобы написать жирным шрифтом ставьте перед и после словом *
2. Чтобы написать курсивом ставьте до и после словом _
3. Чтобы написать зачеркнутым шрифтом ставьте перед и после словом -